# How to convert MongoDB BinData to Guid in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, bindata

i have a BinData in MongoDB and i would convert in Guid in c#. For example this is my Guid in MongoDB document: `BinData(3, 'E7hI3meCkEC5C/KU8w7BRQ==')`
I would convert in c# Guid or c# string.

Thanks

I try to Convert with ConvertFromBase64String but i have an error

Comment: Show the code. To attract high value answers: check your question if it complys to the suggestions in [ask] and improve it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, check this code:

```
        var guid = new Guid();
        var binary = new BsonBinaryData(guid, GuidRepresentation.Standard);
        var result = binary.ToGuid(GuidRepresentation.Standard);
        (guid == result).Should().BeTrue();
```

or:

```
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("E7hI3meCkEC5C/KU8w7BRQ==");
        var binaryData = new BsonBinaryData(bytes, BsonBinarySubType.UuidLegacy);
        var result = binaryData.ToGuid(GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy);
        var guid = new Guid(bytes);
        (guid == result).Should().BeTrue();
```

Comment: And where i insert binaryData array?

Comment: use different overload, see update

Comment: if it works, then resolve a question)